# svg circle - Can't bind to cx since it isn't a known native property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I need to do a progress arc based on the calculated percentage, I have created a custom directive to access the svg attributes from the user, while updating that in my template, I am getting the following error:

> Can't bind to 'cx' since it isn't a known native property
>   Can't bind to 'cy' since it isn't a known native property

etc..

I am getting these sorts of errors for all the svg attributes.

Below is my code in jade:

```
progress-arc([size]="200", [strokeWidth]="20", [stroke]="red", [complete]="0.8")
```

Below is my directive code:

```
import {Component,Input,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:'progress-arc',
  template:`
   <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle fill="white"
          cx="{{parsedSize/2}}"
          cy="{{parsedSize/2}}"
          r="{{radius}}"
          stroke="{{stroke}}"
          stroke-width="{{strokeWidthCapped}}"
          stroke-dasharray="{{circumference}}"
          stroke-dashoffset="{{(1 - parsedComplete) * circumference}}"/>
  </svg>`,
  providers: [],
  directives: []
})
export class ProgressArc implements AfterViewInit {
 @Input('size') size:string;
 @Input('strokeWidth') strokeWidth:string;
 @Input('stroke') stroke:string;
  @Input('complete') complete:string;
  parsedStrokeWidth:number;
  parsedSize:number;
  parsedComplete:number;
  strokeWidthCapped:number;
  radius:number;
  circumference:number;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parsedSize = parseFloat(this.size);
    this.parsedStrokeWidth = parseFloat(this.strokeWidth);
    this.parsedComplete = parseFloat(this.complete);
    this.strokeWidthCapped = Math.min(this.parsedStrokeWidth, this.parsedSize / 2 - 1);
    this.radius = Math.max((this.parsedSize - this.strokeWidthCapped) / 2 - 1, 0);
    this.circumference = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 215):

In order to bind to SVG element attributes in Angular, you must prefix them with `attr`:

For your circle this will be:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle fill="white"
          [attr.cx]="parsedSize/2"
          [attr.cy]="parsedSize/2"
          [attr.r]="radius"
          [attr.stroke]="stroke"
          [attr.stroke-width]="strokeWidthCapped"
          [attr.stroke-dasharray]="circumference"
          [attr.stroke-dashoffset]="(1 - parsedComplete) * circumference"/>
</svg>
```

I am not entirely sure if it should be `[attr.stroke-width]` or `[attr.strokeWidth]`, but give it a shot.

You need to use the `attr` prefix when the attribute has no property associated

Comment: it is working but WHY sometimes we need attr. and somestines no, that is non sense
(edit: I'm posting a question right now)

Comment: Search for the difference between html properties and attributes. If you are binding to attributes you need the prefix

Comment: @PierreDuc can you tell me how the binding looks like if I want to bind two values for stroke-dasharray. something like: [attr.stroke-dasharray]="circumference circumference"

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy sure, you can do it like this: `[attr.stroke-dasharray]="circum1 + ', ' + circum2"`. Or you can do it like this.  `[attr.stroke-dasharray]="{{circum1}}, {{circum2}}"`. Whatever you think is more legible.

Comment: This is still valid as of Angular 8.x

Comment: `[fill]="myColorVariable"`  its not working.  i want to show fill color for selected line.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib as the answer said: `[attr.fill]="myColorVariable"`

Comment: somehow i managed it to work with css. `[ngStyle]="{fill: myColorvariable}"`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib sure that works too. Or `[style.fill]="myColorVariable"`. Did you try the `[attr.fill]` though?

Comment: @PoulKruijt Take a Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657678/show-tooltip-day-wise-on-line-graph-on-peak-or-low-metric

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd chime in if anyone is still using AngularJS.  Use the ng-attr- prefix for attributes to interpolate:

```
 <svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle fill="white"
      cx="{{parsedSize/2}}"
      cy="{{parsedSize/2}}"
      r="{{radius}}"
      stroke="{{stroke}}"
      stroke-width="{{strokeWidthCapped}}"
      stroke-dasharray="{{circumference}}"
      stroke-dashoffset="{{(1 - parsedComplete) * circumference}}"/>
```

Becomes:

```
 <svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle fill="white"
      ng-attr-cx="{{parsedSize/2}}"
      ng-attr-cy="{{parsedSize/2}}"
      ng-attr-r="{{radius}}"
      ng-attr-stroke="{{stroke}}"
      ng-attr-stroke-width="{{strokeWidthCapped}}"
      ng-attr-stroke-dasharray="{{circumference}}"
      ng-attr-stroke-dashoffset="{{(1 - parsedComplete) * circumference}}"/>
```

Note that you keep the curly braces in this case.